# Completely change Android ImageView's color with tint color

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

Is there a way to completely change the color of an `ImageView` in Android? I tried using

```
imageView.getDrawable().setColorFilter(new  PorterDuffColorFilter(0xFFF7962F, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

and

```
imageView.setColorFilter(0xFFDDDDDD, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

on an `ImageView` with a gray image drawable but they only added a color on top of the existing gray making it look kind of weird.

On iOS you can do

```
[imageView setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

And it will completely remove whatever color was used to render the `UIImageView` and replace the "skeleton" image with the designated color. Perhaps it's because the tint always has an alpha transparency on it? I did specify `0xFF` on the alpha part though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the wrong blend mode, MULTIPLY combines both source colour and the colour you're adding. You probably want this:

`imageView.setColorFilter(0xFFDDDDDD, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`